Tkinterで作成し保存した画像が真っ白になってしまう
Pythonプログラムの練習としてTkinterで作ったペイント風アプリで画像を保存すると、画面が真っ白になって保存されてしまいます。
作成した画像をそのまま保存できるようにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか。
いろいろ調べましたが、解決策がわからず質問させていただきました。
背景を黒にして文字を白にしているのはあえてやっています。
どこが悪いのかわからないのでコード全文入れておきます。
いろいろなサイトからコードを流用しています。ご認識ください。
ペイント画面

保存後の画像

コード全文
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageTk, ImageDraw, EpsImagePlugin

WIDTH = 5

cd = os.path.abspath(".")

class Paint:
    def __init__(self):
        # 操作中の図形のID
        self.curr_id = -1
        
        # メインウィンドウ作成
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title("ペイント")
        root.geometry("280x280")

        # 画像表示用キャンバス作成
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, bg="black")
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
        # キーバインド
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_key_left)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.dragging)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", self.save_image)

        root.mainloop()

    # マウス左ボタン押下
    def on_key_left(self, event):
        # 直線描画
        self.curr_id = self.canvas.create_line(event.x, event.y, event.x, event.y, fill="white", width=WIDTH)
 
   # ドラッグ中
    def dragging(self, event):
        points = self.canvas.coords(self.curr_id)
        points.extend([event.x,event.y])
        self.canvas.coords(self.curr_id, points)

    # 右クリックで保存
    def save_image(self, event):
        # postscriptとして一時保存
        self.canvas.postscript(file="test.ps") 
        # postscriptを読み取り
        saveimg= Image.open(cd+"/test.ps")
        saveimg = saveimg.convert('1')
        # postscroptを別形式で保存
        saveimg.save(cd+"/test.png")

        print("セーフ完了!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if True:
        Paint()


形式を何度か変換されていますのでどこまで正常でどこからおかしくなったのか確認されると良いかと思います。

PostScript の場合、background color(つまり「紙」の色)は指定できません。(ページと同じサイズの黒色の画像を重ねることで同じ結果を得ることは可能ですが) 例えば、描画する線分の色を赤(red)に変更してみると判るかと思います。self.curr_id = self.canvas.create_line(event.x, event.y, event.x, event.y, fill="red", width=WIDTH)

@metropolisさんのコメント内容や、こちらの記事が当てはまるでしょう。
Canvas background color not saved
回答は以下のように記述されています。

I don't believe the postscript command is designed to preserve the background color of the canvas widget. It only saves the items that appear on the canvas.
A simple solution is to draw a rectangle that is the exact size of the canvas, and change the color of that rectangle.


PostScript コマンドは、キャンバス ウィジェットの背景色を保存するようには設計されていないと思います。キャンバスに表示される項目のみを保存します。
簡単な解決策は、キャンバスとまったく同じサイズの長方形を描画し、その長方形の色を変更することです。

Tk::Canvas - Create and manipulate Canvas widgetsの$canvas->postscript(?option, value, option, value, ...?)の項目にも背景色に関連するオプションは無さそうです。
例えばこちらで解説されている内容を適用すれば：
【Python】Tkinterのcanvasを使ってみる
質問のdef __init__(self):メソッドの以下の部分に黒い四角を書いておけば良いと思われます。(####のコメント付きの行を追加)
        root.geometry("280x280")

        # 画像表示用キャンバス作成
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, bg="black")
        self.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 280, 280, fill='black') #### postscript出力用背景塗りつぶし設定：サイズは上記root.geometry("280x280")と同じ範囲を指定


回答ありがとうございます。いただいたコードで想定の挙動ができました。
postscript自体に背景色に関する設定がなかったのですね。そこは調べていませんでした。
